# Files copied to a flash drive not showing up on iPad file system

Tags: files

I formatted a flash drive on my Mac and then copied files from my windows server on to it. But the files are not showing up when I use the flash drive on my Mac. But It also shows that The drive is out of space, what am I missing here.

Comment: Check if hibernated. Default with Windows 8 or 10 is fast startup which sets a hibernation flag on every partition. Then other systems (even Windows 7) will not be able to mount that hibernated partition. You may be able to force mount read only, but not sure how to do that on a Mac, just Ubuntu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: See also: External drive, use safe eject or try manual mount read only with recover
https://superuser.com/questions/1231582/hdd-with-windows-boot-locked-because-of-hibernation-flag